# Туториал PongGame. Не работает анимация шарика, хотя все списано с оригинала

Tags: python, kivy

Все работает кроме анимации шарика. Он не двигается.
Mой код

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.graphics import Ellipse, Rectangle, Color, Line
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from random import randint


class PongGame(FloatLayout):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(size=self.info)
        self.add_widget(Label(pos_hint={'x': -0.1, 'y': 0.3}, text='0', font_size=70))
        self.add_widget(Label(pos_hint={'x': 0.1, 'y': 0.3}, text='0', font_size=70))

    def serve_ball(self):
        self.ball.velocity=Vector(4,0).rotate(randint(0,360))

    def info(self, instance, value):
        print(self.ball.pos)
        print(' Размер окна: ', self.size,
              'Позиция окна: ', self.pos,
              'Центр окна: ', self.center,
              'Высота окна: ', self.height,
              'Ширина окна: ', self.width)

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()
        if (self.ball.y < 0) or (self.ball.y > self.height):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1
        if (self.ball.x<0) or (self.ball.x>self.width):
            self.ball.velocity_x *= -1


class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(self.velocity) + self.pos


class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game=PongGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1/60)
        return PongGame()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

KV

```
# File name: PingPong.py
#:kivy 1.10.0
<PongBall>:
    size_hint: (0.05,0.07)
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball

    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x-5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
```

[Оригинальный код с сайта киви](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/examples/tutorials/pong/steps/step4)

Comment: Что меняли в коде? Не нужно весь код, если он списан с оригинала.Оригинал прекрасно работает. Лог в студию! Завтра посмотрю ваш код подробнее.

Answer (score 1):

У вас `self.velocity`

```
def move(self):
    self.pos = Vector(self.velocity) + self.pos
```

В оригинальном коде  `*self.velocity`

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/tutorials/pong/steps/step4/main.py#L16